# Autosys Workload Automation same as CA Workload Automation AE?

Tags: broadcom

Is Autosys Workload Automation same as CA Workload Automation AE?

Is CA Workload Automation Desktop Client licensable under CA Workload Automation AE or AutoSys Workload Automation? Can you please provide reference link? Thank you!

I researched but could not find conclusive evidence.